# How to run a subprocess command to start a nodejs server in the background Python

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, subprocess

I have successfully started a node server script through a `subprocess` call and capture the output in python:

```
subprocess.check_output(["node", "path/to/script"])
```

Now, because python is synchronous it doesn't run any code after that line above as it's waiting for the server to 'finish'. I need to run the node script by using that command and then immediately allow all code after that line but have the ability to capture every output from the server.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

After MarsNebulaSoup's answer with using asyncio, no code is ran until the nodejs server is stopped:

```
async def setupServer():
    output = subprocess.run(["node", '/path/to/app.js'])
    print('continuing')

async def setupController():
    print('Running other code...')

async def mainAsync():
    await asyncio.gather(setupServer(), setupController())


asyncio.run(mainAsync())
print('THIS WILL RUN ONCE THE SEVER HAS SETUP HAS STOPPED')
```

It will come as this order:

1. 'Output of the subprocess command'
2. ONLY AFTER THE SERVER HAS STOPPED: 'continuing'
3. 'Running other code...'
4. 'THIS WILL RUN ONCE THE SEVER HAS SETUP HAS STOPPED'

Comment: Don't you mean "python is synchronous"?

Comment: It sounds like you need async functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup ahahah, yes sorry spelling mistake....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python's threading module to create and run threads. The code should work this time, as I created a test JS script file and, indeed it opens this time, while the other code is running:

```
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import time

def runServer():
  print('Starting server...\n')
  output = subprocess.run(["node", 'script.js'])
  print('Done running server...')

server = Thread(target=runServer) #you can create as many threads as you need
server.start()

#other code goes here
for x in range(0,15):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

script.js:

```
console.log('Starting script...')
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Script finished"); }, 10000);
```

Output:

```
Starting server...
0

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Done running server...
11
12
13
14
```

As you can see, the server finishes running while the other code is running. Hopefully you won't have any problems when running this, but let me know if you do.

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you! I assume anything after `asyncio.run(main())` will run once both have finished?

Comment: Cheers, great answer!

Comment: After some testing, no code is being run when the node.js server is running, not even code within the other async function. I need to run code whilst the server is running, then stop the server after the code has finished...?

Comment: Okay. I am looking into it

Comment: No problem, it may be just me but I thought your solution would've worked, I wouldnt see why it doesn't?? Thanks

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Your async code helped too as I will need that going forward. Appreciate the time bro!